# Loading twitter data using JSONP in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to get some data from twitter using jsonp. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/k7MMj/9/) is the jsfiddle for the code. So, there is nothing  too complicated about the code. It even works fine inside jsFiddle window, but as soon as I put it in javascript file inside an on ready function, nothing happens in chrome. I have looked into this many times and can't seem to get anywhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can we see the script you're using that isn't working?

Comment: Could be that other JS code is broken on your site. Does `$(function({alert('work?');});`

Comment: So, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k7MMj/18/) is little bit of what I am trying to do, making a list of names for the ids. The strange thing is that the page works fine in Firefox but nothing happens in Chrome, even the error function does not fire. Its probably something that I am not seeing, will keep looking.

Comment: and I did try the alerts and console.log inside success function. They work fine in Firefox, but not in chrome.

Comment: Feeling a bit embarrassed, but turns out if you use fonts from google APIs like <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rochester' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>, then JSONP requests do not work. Not sure why that is, but after removing that, data is appearing to load.

Comment: @Abhinav: Why don't you add that as an answer and then mark it as answered?

Comment: I didn't think I could answer my question myself, but makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

ffs, just spilled coffee all over my laptops keyboard. anyway,
if it's only for a one-time data fetch you dont have to use jQuery.ajax..

here is a  simple solution.

```
<script>
function DataFromTwitter(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
</script>
<script src="http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=15,16,17,18&callback=DataFromTwitter"></script>
```

enjoy